# how to loop over angular js object , and add object to the looped

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop

Am trying to loop over an object in angular-js and add an array to object foreach looped object , my code is as below but doesn't seem to work

```
vm.patients= [
        {[ {"p1": "value1"} ]},
        {[ {"p1": "value1"} ]},
        {[ {"p1": "value1"} ]}

    }];

for(var i=0; i < vm.patients.length; i++){
vm.patients[i].concat([{"z1": "z2",}]);`
}
```

My aim is to add `{"z1": "z2",}` to each loop ie the 3 loops arrays so that i end with below

```
vm.patients= [
            {[ {"p1": "value1"},{"z1": "z2",} ]},
            {[ {"p1": "value1"},{"z1": "z2",} ]},
            {[ {"p1": "value1"},{"z1": "z2",} ]}

        }];
```

`concat` however doesn't seem to work , any solution ?

Comment: `vm.patients` is not an array.  you need to use brackets `[ ]` to define an array

Comment: you concat an object to string what did you expect?

Comment: `patients` doesn't have a length property

Comment: Patients is an object not an array. If you wish to itterate it you should use a `for in` loop. However the order of properties iterated cannot be predicted or guaranteed.

Comment: Are you aware you have an strange accent mark there? ...({"z1": "z2",});`

Comment: either its an object, then you have properties or it is an array, then you have no properties, but elements.

Comment: `vm.patients` is a returned dataset from a database , in this case using laravel Eloquent ORM

Comment: ok, but what is in it?

Comment: Laravel never returned me anything in that format. Perhaps you processed your code somehow?

Comment: above is just an example the dataset is so huge i cant put it here

Comment: actually, it is not valid code, because objects requires properties, at least one.

Comment: have updated , @Glenn Ferrie answer seems to solve it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
var vm = {};
vm.patients = [{
        "p1": "value1",
        "p2": "value2",
        "p3": "value3"
    }];

for(var i=0; i < vm.patients.length; i++){
    var p = vm.patients[i];
    p["z1"] = "z2";
}
// The result here is that each element in the array will have an
// addition attribute named z1 with the value of "z2".
```

You had some syntax issues with your JavaScript, but this code is cleaner.

I made `patients` into an array and modified your other code that affects change on the items in the array.

Comment: this looks promising let me test this !

Answer (score 6):

You don't iterate your objects using a `for(;;)` loop, if they're not array-like objects.

You can iterate with `for(in)`, however:

```
for(var key in yourObj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = yourObj[key];
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Or angularjs-fashion:

```
angular.forEach(yourObj, function(value, key) {
    // your code here
})
```

Additionally:

```
vm.patients[i].concat([{"z1": "z2",}]);
```

is wrong, since you are calling something like "patient1".concat([{"z1": "z2"}]) which:

1. Does not alter the value. Try executing in the console the following code:

   ```
    var x = "a";
    x.concat("b");
    console.log(x);
   ```
2. Sounds to be wrong. Try executing the following in the console:

   ```
    var x = "a";
    console.log(x.concat([{'a':'b'}]))
   ```

   and see what happens.

**Tip**: If you have troubles with your code, try separating all the code in single instructions and assignments.

Perhaps you intended:

```
var yourObj = {
    "p1": {"name": "patient1"},
    ... others ...
};
angular.forEach(yourObj, function(value, key) {
    // your code here
    angular.extend(value, {"z1": "z2"})
})
```

Comment: while the question is unclear, the answer remains unclear.

Answer (score 1):

concat is an Array function, you can not use it over an object. secondly, if you want to use concat, second parameter also should be an array : `[1].concat([2,4])`.
third, you are trying to concat something to a string which is can't be concat with an object.
Then, 
If you want to iterate over the object and extend it, you should do :

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(ob) {
  obj[ob] = Object.assign(obj[ob], {newParam1: 1, newParam2: 2});
});
```

but you code in angular this is more appropriate :

```
angular.forEach(obj, function(v) {
  v = angular.extend(v, {newValue1: 1, newValue2: 2});
});
```

Comment: what does v stand for ?

Comment: object instance in your array

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a data structure like

```
vm.patients = [{ p1: "value1" }, { p1: "value1" }, { p1: "value1" }];
```

then this would work:

```js
var vm = {};
vm.patients = [{ p1: "value1" }, { p1: "value1" }, { p1: "value1" }];

vm.patients.forEach(function (a) {
    a.z1 = 'z2';
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(vm.patients, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```